# Duplicate Check Multiple Modules In SuiteCRM On Import

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm trying to duplicate check against multiple modules when importing data into SuiteCRM.

As a simplified example, lets say I have two custom modules which store both Senders and Receivers. A Customer can be both a Sender and a Receiver however, if we import a list of Senders I would like to ensure that none of these Senders are already in the CRM as a Receiver. We can do this by checking the VAT Numbers.

Is there a way to do a duplicate check like this?